# Update elements of array of object when one element is changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

The below question is different than the one which shows that it is a duplidate. Here i am trying to update several other elements inside an object when a match is found.

I have the below array of objects

```
Array[0-1]
   0: Object
       Id: 1
       MonthlySalary: 100
       YearlySalary: 1200
       Deductions: 240
   1: Object
       Id: 2
       MonthlySalary: 200
       YearlySalary: 2400
       Deductions: 480
```

I get MonthlySalary from database and i calculate YearlySalary and Deductions at the front end. YearlySalary is 12 times MonthlySalary and Deductions is 20% of YearlySalary.

Now, whenever i update MonthlySalary value at UI. For eg. I update the 1st array[0] from 100 to 300. When i update the monthly salary, i do get the Id which is being updated. So i get that Id:1 is being updated.

Now i need to go through this array of objects, find the element which has Id as 1 and update all the releated MonthlySalary, YearlySalary and deductions for that id:1

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. The final result should look like this below.

```
Array[0-1]
   0: Object
       Id: 1
       MonthlySalary: 300
       YearlySalary: 3600
       Deductions: 720
   1: Object
       Id: 2
       MonthlySalary: 200
       YearlySalary: 2400
       Deductions: 480
```

Comment: You can use `_.find` method to find your object which has `id` you want to modify data and then update its `value`
e.g.
var data = [{id:1, val:10},{id:2, val:20}];
_.find(data, function(item) {
    return item.id == 1; 
}).val = 30;

Comment: For more clarification you can refer this link https://jsfiddle.net/c_Dhananjay/dc4r73fp/